# Document Sections

Tags: c#, ms-word, export, sections

I am exporting data from a database to a word document in WinForms using C#

The resultant document has 5 Sections due to using:

```
Range.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
```

What i wish to know is, how do i refer to each section individually - so i can set a different header for each section, instead of doing this:

```
 foreach (Section section in aDoc.Sections)
            {
                //Get the header range and add the header details.
                var headerRange = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
                headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBlack;
                headerRange.Font.Size = 14;
                headerRange.Font.Name = "Arial";
                headerRange.Font.Bold = 1;
                headerRange.Text = Some Header Here;
                headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
           }
```

Because this sets every header to "Some Header Here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when new sections are generated in a Word document, the property `LinkToPrevious` is set to True. This means that the new section "inherits" the headers and footers of the previous section.

In order to have different header/footer content in each section, it's necessary to set `LinkToPrevious` to False. This can be done as you create the sections, or at any time after that, but it should be done *before* you write content to a header/footer. If the link is broken *after* the header/footer contains content, that content will be lost (but does remain in the "parent" header/footer to which the section was linked).

So to address an individual Section, remove the link, and write content to its Header you can:

```
Word.Section sec = doc.Sections[indexValue]
Word.HeaderFooter hf = sec.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
hf.LinkToPrevious = false;
hf.Range.Text = "Content for this header";
```

Note: There is no need to write the sections to a List in order to give them different content.

Comment: thank you for your response, i will try this tomorrow when i am at a PC :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Sections` property is just an untyped IEnumerable, you can do the following to make a typed list of sections from it. Notice that you need to import `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic` namespaces for this to work.

```
List<Section> sections = new List<Section>(aDoc.Sections.Cast<Sections>());
```

Now, if you need to set specific section's header, you can write

```
Section section1 = sections[0];
var section1HeaderRange = section1.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
section1HeaderRange.Text = "Section 1 Header";

Section section2 = sections[1];
var section2HeaderRange = section2.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
section2HeaderRange.Text = "Section 2 Header";
```

Comment: thanks for your response! - i cant attempt it right now as im not at a pc, and wont be for a few days. Will update when i do :)